# Tikz: Adding extra information in the legend

Tags: pgfplots

I want to add extra information to the legend. I did this in the MWE, where I created a dummy plot in order to add extra info in the legend. How can this be done without creating a fake \addplot?
Thank you.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymax = 3000,
        ymin = -3000,
        height=9cm,
        width=9cm,
        grid=major,
    ]

    \addplot {-x^5 - 242};
    \addlegendentry{model}

    \addplot coordinates {
        (-4.77778,2027.60977)
        (-3.55556,347.84069)
        (-2.33333,22.58953)
        (-1.11111,-493.50066)
        (0.11111,46.66082)
        (1.33333,-205.56286)
        (2.55556,-341.40638)
        (3.77778,-1169.24780)
        (5.00000,-3269.56775)
    };
    \addlegendentry{estimate}

    \addplot[only marks,white] coordinates {(-1,-15000)}; % dummy plot to add extra legend entry.....
    \addlegendentry{Additional Information}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magical command line is

```
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
```

I also suggest to add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`, but this is not needed here.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}% <-added but not necessary
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymax = 3000,
        ymin = -3000,
        height=9cm,
        width=9cm,
        grid=major,
    ]

    \addplot {-x^5 - 242};
    \addlegendentry{model}

    \addplot coordinates {
        (-4.77778,2027.60977)
        (-3.55556,347.84069)
        (-2.33333,22.58953)
        (-1.11111,-493.50066)
        (0.11111,46.66082)
        (1.33333,-205.56286)
        (2.55556,-341.40638)
        (3.77778,-1169.24780)
        (5.00000,-3269.56775)
    };
    \addlegendentry{estimate}

    \addlegendimage{empty legend}
    \addlegendentry{Additional Information}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]